# Extract all the JSON data using Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: json, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Volley library to communicate with my API. I'm pretty new to Android and Kotlin and I'm really confused about extracting keys from the following JSON data

```
{
  "message": {
    "_id": "60bc7fa7abeedb25643fa692",
    "hash": "3a54b415461a63abac1fc6dfa0e140584047bd15358e33a177f9505ed2faa4d4",
    "blockchain": "ethereum",
    "amount": 5000,
    "amount_usd": 13352971,
    "from": "d3d69228cb2292f933572399593617f574c70eb1",
    "to": "fe9996da73d6bf5252f15024811954ae37ab68be",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

The volley library returns all of this JSON data in a variable called response and I'm using `response.getString("message")` to extract the message key but, I don't understand how to extract the internal data such as `hash, blockchain, amount, etc.`

I'm using the following code to get the JSON data from my backend.

```
val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                { response ->

                    tweet_text.setText(response.getString("message"))

                    Log.d("resp", response.toString())
                },
                {
                    Log.d("err", it.localizedMessage)
                })
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You should look into JSON serialization libraries, such as Kotlinx Serialization. It would be way more practical to handle. If it's your own API, and you write the server in Kotlin too, you can even share your data model with your android app and rely on automatic serialization/deserialization to/from JSON, so you don't have to write it twice.

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks for the info! Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, I just used the `getJSONObject()` method to make it work

```
val jsonRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                { response ->

                    val txn = response.getJSONObject("message")
                    //txn object can be used to extract the internal data

                },
                {
                    Log.d("err", it.localizedMessage)
                })
```